# How to pass parameters in react native websoket?

Tags: react-native

We need to pass that parmates when connect to server this is my code but its not working:

```
let socket = new WebSocket(socket_url,{ query: token=${token}room=${chatId} });       
socket.onopen = function (e) {
    alert("[open] Connection established");
    socket.send("My name is Sachin");
};

socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    alert(`[message] Data received from server: ${event.data}`);
};

socket.onclose = function (event) {
    if (event.wasClean) {
        alert(`[close] Connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code} reason=${event.reason}`);
    } else {
        // e.g. server process killed or network down
        // event.code is usually 1006 in this case
        //alert('[close] Connection died');
    }
};

socket.onerror = function (error) {
    alert(`[error] ${error.message}`);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 let socket = new WebSocket(`${socket_url}?token=${token}&room=${chatId}`);
```